# md-select initialization with i18n

Tags: angularjs, i18next, angular-material

I'm using Angular-material and I18next. Here is my simple example :

```
<md-select ng-init="val='en'" ng-model="val">
    <md-option ng-value="en">{{'en' | i18next}}</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="de">{{'de' | i18next}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

**The select title is initialized with 'en' and not 'English'**. But as soon as I select an other value the correct internationnalized value appears as the new select title.

Any idea how to get the select element displaying the internationnalized value from its initialization ?

Thanks,
Max

N.B. if I initializes directly with 'English' or any other value different than the values in the options, the select element does not get initialized at all.

Update: It looks like the md-select element title is initialized before the md-option elements inner values are internationnalized. I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was bug in older angular-material.js which you were referring [**Github Issue**](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1760) & It has been resolved in newer version.

Try updating Your angular-material.js to latest(ver. 1.3.6) will select the value properly.

**HTML**

```
<md-select ng-init="val='en'" ng-model="val">
    <md-option ng-value="en">{{'en' | i18next}}</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="de">{{'de' | i18next}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EBnm3V?p=preview)

**Update**

In order work drop down pre-selected value with `i18next` filter you need to set 
useLocalStorage option to true to preserve all files like ``useLocalStorage: true,`

**Config**

```
app.config(['$i18nextProvider',
  function($i18nextProvider) {
    $i18nextProvider.options = {
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      useCookie: true,
      useLocalStorage: true, //set to true
      resGetPath: 'i18n-__lng__.json',
      lngWhitelist: ['en', 'de'],
      preload: ['en', 'de']
    };
  }
]);
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4TS0Zl?p=preview)

Hopefully this would help you, Thanks.

Comment: @max can you reproduce your problem here http://plnkr.co/edit/vviv7aiT5dJcSBLlv8nf?p=preview? Might be i didn't get you properly..

Comment: It seems that on plnk only the "values" of the options elements are displayed as select title. How can I display the inner tag value of the option elements as select title ?

Comment: @Max I didn't get you, which inner tag value you are talking about?

Comment: <option value="value">innerTagValue</option>

Comment: @Max  you mean to say i18next filter doesn't work on initial load

Comment: I mean that even this does not show, as the select element title, the translated value :

`<md-select ng-init="val='en'" ng-model="val">
      <md-option value="en">English</md-option>
      <md-option value="de">German</md-option>
    </md-select>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72468/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-max).